# Corrupt memory with LockBits (DirectShow webcam)

Tags: .net, vb.net, directshow, lockbits

I'm doing some image manipulation in .NET (VB 2010). I'm using the following code (which doesn't do anything yet):

```
Sub Manipulate(IMG As Bitmap)
    ' Dim foo(100000) As Integer  - will need it later...

    Dim bd = IMG.LockBits(New Rectangle(0, 0, IMG.Width, IMG.Height),
                          Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
                          Imaging.PixelFormat.Format24bppRgb)
    Dim absstride = Math.Abs(bd.Stride)
    Dim numbytes = absstride * IMG.Height
    Dim bytes(numbytes - 1) As Byte
    Dim flipped = bd.Stride < 0
    Dim ptr = If(flipped, bd.Scan0 - numbytes + absstride, bd.Scan0)
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, bytes, 0, numbytes)

    ' I'm going to put sg here

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(bytes, 0, ptr, numbytes)
    IMG.UnlockBits(bd)
End Sub
```

This works perfectly for simple purposes (eg. brightening the image), but my algorithm needs some big variables (see 'foo' above). When declaring it (uncomment that line), I suddenly get exceptions:
depending on the size of 'foo'...

...either the first Marshal.Copy() throws
AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

...or the declaration of 'bytes' throws
FatalExecutionEngineError: The runtime has encountered a fatal error. The address of the error was at 0x6819d142, on thread 0x3690. The error code is 0xc0000005. This error may be a bug in the CLR or in the unsafe or non-verifiable portions of user code. Common sources of this bug include user marshaling errors for COM-interop or PInvoke, which may corrupt the stack.

...or no exceptions at all and everything works fine.

What is going on?

**Additional info:** I get the image objects from webcam using DirectShow.

Comment: Get rid of flipped, the bitmap never starts before Scan0.  And never run this code on a bitmap that you got from a callback that is no longer executing.  Unless you make a deep copy of the bitmap with the Bitmap(Image) constructor.

Comment: @HansPassant I know in theory I should always copy from Scan0, but that just won't work when flipped is true. This way I copy from the right memory location, I checked it with Bitmap.GetPixel().

Comment: @HansPassant Making a deep copy does solve the issue, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

As Hans pointed out, I have to make a deep copy of the bitmap and everything works. Otherwise I'm using an image that is already disposed. This is a silent error though, until I declare some big variables, which use up the disposed memory, that's when the GC throws some seemingly random errors.